# Cant access Google and facebook

Tags: networking, internet, google, facebook

I am using Ubuntu from last 5 years. From last 3 days i am experiencing a problem related to internet, I am unable to open either **google.com** or **facebook.com** for first half an hour, allother websites are working, after half an hour or so they are opening. I tried even with **ping** command, but same result.

Comment: can you ping 8.8.8.8?

Comment: have you tried other https sites? both google and facebook auto-force an https connection.

Comment: i haven’t tried this, but i can ping it right now, (its already more than one hour since I booted Ubuntu)

Comment: @mchid I have tried https://yahoo.com, its working. but https://www.facebook.com/ and https://www.google.co.in/ and https://www.google.com/ are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are experiencing an issue with your web browser.  I'll explain.

Beginning about 9 months ago, I began having problems with various web browsers, not all google browsers.  The Google Chromium browser to be found in the software center worked on older computers but not newer ones, different version apparently.  Firefox worked right for about two weeks and then began having the same issues as Google.  Everyone I talked to, everyone using Ubuntu, said the same thing.

To this very day I am forced to use THREE BROWSERS to do all I need to do without being burdened by and unexplained browser crash, video that won't load, or tool that won't work.  My browsers of choice currently are the Ubuntu included Firefox, Opera, and Google Chrome browser.  That's Chrome, not Chromium.  Google for "install google chrome" and your first result will assist you installing it under Ubuntu).

Installing Opera is far more complicated than Chrome, but it can be done.  I've done it on not less than five installations but it always takes me nearly half an hour.  Opera also seems to be the most functional, which is why I am bothering to mention it.  There is no harm in having more than one browser, in fact I recommend always having two handy.

Comment: I have currently using Firefox 36.0.4, but i have tried using Ubuntu web browser, but it also has same problem, does it a browser related issue OR  a system problem ?

Comment: The problems I've had, and witnessed on the systems of others, suggest that each browser has its own weaknesses.  It appears, in my personal opinion that various IT security issues, (probably mainly "The Heartbleed Bug") inspired many websites to alter their security, and each browser has had to try to keep up with the changes, some doing better than others, and breaking certain functions along the way.

Comment: there is a developer release of opera that's available for ubuntu you have to look for it but the standard opera for linux is so outdated I wouldn't even trust it

Comment: mchid, December 2014 doesn't seem that old to me.  Please see this link.  These are the instructions I used.  It appears to be self updating and works perfectly.  

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OperaBrowser